# Кастомный обратный отсчет времени

Tags: java, android, datetime, countdown

Как реализовать следующее на Android
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: CustomView рисовать, либо поискать либу, если кто-то уже такое делал.

Comment: @A-Z, как я понял многие боятся кастомных вьюх, думают, что сложно, на самом деле такой виджет можно реализовать обычными лэйаутами)

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 2):

Если не обязательна анимация при изменении времени, то проще будет сделать сверстать все на обычных View где каждая единица времени будет обычным TextView с нужным беком.

Если же хочется с анимацией то можно заморочиться с флипами View

Еще как вариант сделать все на gif, где каждая гифка будет анимировать переход от одного числа к другому

Алгоритм реализации без анимации

1. Для начала нужно просто научиться выводить в них время, а потом стилизовать их будет просто.
2. 8 TextView стоят в ряд по горизонтали и каждый из них отвечает за свое число.
3. Создаешь метод который на вход принимает `Calendar` с временем и выводит его в эти `TextVuew`
4. Затем создаешь `CountDownTimer` который каждый шаг при помощи метода из п.3 выводит оставшееся время
5. Стилизуешь вьюху как тебе хочется
6. Очень долго сношаешься для того что бы это анимировать)

Comment: желательно конечно с анимацией. Но пока хотя бы без.
Вообще в ступоре пока как реализовать

Comment: Если без анимации, то я бы сделал так. 

1. Для начала нужно просто научиться выводить в них время, а потом стилизовать их будет просто. 

2 .8 TextView стоят в ряд по горизонтали и каждый из них отвечает за свое число.

В качестве таймера предлагаю использовать CountDownTimer

Comment: спасибо за совет. Попробую.

Comment: Более развернутый ответ добавил в пост